# At Brisbane King George Square bus station, how do you find out where your bus goes from?

Tags: public-transport, buses, brisbane

In Brisbane, there's a fairly new bus underground bus stop on the busway tunnel at King George Square. There are only two platforms, one for each direction, but each platform is several hundred meters long. On each platform, there are 6 different stops along it, A-F, and bus routes are assigned to one of these stop doors.

Short of walking the length of the platform until you find a stop that lists your bus number, is there any way to know which stop along the platform a given route uses? Perhaps a central display board somewhere, or some way to check online beforehand? For regular users, they'll know which stop, but for a tourist told a route number and to go to King George Square busway station it's a bit more of a challenge!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [Translink Online Journey Planner](http://jp.translink.com.au/travel-information/journey-planner/), then for journeys involving King George Square station the planner will tell you which part of the platform to use, eg

> 7.10pm Depart King George Square station, platform 2D

That involves having internet access to look up your journey details, which may not be available.

If you arrive at the station without having the chance to check online, then there is a big bank of screens above the escalators to each platform. These show the next 5 buses to call at each stop along the platform. Depending on the stop and the time of day, this could be anything between 5 minutes into the future and over an hour, so you may see what you need up there, or you may not. All depends on how soon until your bus. The displays look something like this:

[image: The information screens]

Alternately, there is a map of which routes use which stop. Annoyingly, it doesn't seem to be available anywhere around the station entrance, nor just after arriving on the platform. I only found it almost at the far end of the platform, where it's much less use as you've already walked past most of the stop information boards! The photo below is a bit blury, but should at least give you an idea of the information poster to look for if you need it.

[image: The map, not apparently available in many places]

So, short answer - if you have internet and/or your bus leaves in a few minutes, you're fine. Otherwise, you'll probably have to walk along the platform checking each stop, unless Translink decide to be helpful and put up some more of the "which stop" posters in useful places...